# Selecting specific <tr> tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am fetching some html table rows with BeautifulSoup with this piece of code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

page = urllib2.urlopen('www.something.bla')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
rows = soup.findAll('tr', attrs={'class': re.compile('class1.*')})
```

This is what I get as a result:

```
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">...</tr>
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">...</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">...</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">...</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">...</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">...</tr>
<!-- etc. -->
```

However, I'd like to exclude (or not select them in the first place) those rows which have `class1 class2 class3` as an attribute.

How can I do that?
Thanks for help!

Comment: So is `class1_a` okay to grab just not `class1`?

Comment: I should grab all of them which start with `class1*` but not those which also have `class2 class3`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier without regex. This works with BeautifulSoup 3:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">1</tr>
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">2</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">3</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">4</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">5</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">6</tr>
<tr>7</tr>"""

def cond(x):
    if x:
        return x.startswith("class1") and not "class2 class3" in x
    else:
        return False

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
rows = soup.findAll('tr', {'class': cond})

for row in rows:
    print row
```

=>

```
<tr class="class1 class5">3</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">4</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">5</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">6</tr>
```

---

With BeautifulSoup 4, I was able to make it work as follows:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">1</tr>
<tr class="class1 class2 class3">2</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">3</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">4</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">5</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">6</tr>
<tr>7</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
rows = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': re.compile('class1.*')})

for row in rows:
    cls = row.attrs.get("class")
    if not ("class2" in cls or "class3" in cls):
        print row
```

=>

```
<tr class="class1 class5">3</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">4</tr>
<tr class="class1 class5">5</tr>
<tr class="class1_a class5_a">6</tr>
```

In BS4, multi-valued attributes like `class` have lists of strings as their values, not strings. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id12.

Comment: Ah yes, lambda :) seems very classy :) However, I get an error in that line: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`... I've never used lamba functions before and have tried to 'fix' this error but didn't get any far actually :-/

Comment: It doesn't have to be a lambda. Answer updated with code to handle cases when there is no `class` attribute and x = `None` (as is the case for `<tr>` 7 in my example).

Comment: Thanks for helping with this, however no matter which one of your examples I try, I always get different return than yours in console - I get all rows except row 7. :/

Comment: Damn the versions :) Yes, I was always trying it in bs4... It works perfectly now! Many many thanks!